# Difference between this.innerHTML and function(event) when used with an eventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, this, event-listener

This is my first time ever posting here so please forgive me if it's a bit confusing :)

I am new to Javascript and currently following Dr.Yu's Udemy Course for web developers.
I'm having trouble understanding the difference between `this.innerHTML` and `function(event)`. In my understanding, the event will tap into the events that triggered the event listener, while this will give me the identity of the object that triggered the event. I feel like in my case, they both give me the identity of the thing that triggered the event, so I don't see why I cannot use `function (event)` for detecting pressed buttons.
Below is my code:

```
// Detecting pressed button
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        makeSound(event.key);
    });
}
//detecting pressed keyboard 
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    makeSound(event.key);
});

function makeSound(key) {
    switch (key) {
        case "w":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-1.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;
        case "a":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-2.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;
        case "s":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;

        case "d":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;


        case "j":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;

        case "k":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;

        case "l":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;

        default:
            console.log(buttenInnerHTML);

    }
}
```

The correct code for Detecting pressed button is below:

//Detecting pressed button
//Why can't we use function(event) for the click as well?

```
for (var i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;i++){
document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
var buttenInnerHTML =this.innerHTML;
makeSound(buttenInnerHTML);
```

});
}

I have tried this code, but it not working properly.

```
//Detecting pressed button 
for (var i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;i++){
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click",function(event){
    makeSound(event.key);});

    function makeSound (key){
    switch (key) {
    case "w":
        var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-1.mp3');
        audio.play();
        break;
    case "a":
        var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-2.mp3');
        audio.play();
        break;
    case "s":
        var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
        audio.play();
        break;
    
    case "d":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;
        
            
    case "j":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;
        
    case "k":
                var audio = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
                audio.play();
                break;
           
    case "l":
                    var audio = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
                    audio.play();
                    break;

                default:console.log(buttenInnerHTML);
                
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`event.key` is only present for a `KeyboardEvent` such as `"keydown"`. A click is not associated with a key being pressed, so it does not work.

More practically, here it makes more sense for pressing a button to play a sound corresponding to the content of the button, which can be accessed with `innerHTML` (or more appropriately, `textContent`).

Comment: This makes total sense, I am not sure why I did not see it this way before. Thank you so much!!